# LINQ Inner Join - Return From Both Tables

Tags: c#, linq, inner-join

I have the following query

```
var customers = from customer in context.tblAccounts 
                join assoc in context.tblAccountAssociations on customer.AccountCode equals assoc.ChildCode 
                where customer.AccountType == "S" || customer.AccountType == "P" 
                select customer, assoc;
```

C# does not like the  "assoc" at the end.

My error message is:

A local variable named 'assoc' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'assoc', which is already used in a 'child' scope to denote something else.

I need to return all columns from both table and then iterate with a

foreach (var customer in customers)

Comment: Can't you just... change the name of the variable?

Comment: Do you need 2 separate objects returned or do you need a property of the customer object populated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you have this line:

```
select customer, assoc;
```

Are you trying to return a customer, an assoc, or both?  Assuming the latter, you can combine them using anonymous types:

```
select new { Customer = customer, Assoc = assoc };
```

Then each item in `customers` would have two properties, `Customer` and `Assoc` and you can grab what you need from either.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap both of the items in an anonymous type.

```
var customers = from customer in context.tblAccounts 
            join assoc in context.tblAccountAssociations on customer.AccountCode equals assoc.ChildCode 
            where customer.AccountType == "S" || customer.AccountType == "P" 
            select new {customer, assoc};
```