# LINQ Inner Join - Return one object from anonymous which is combined from Both Tables

Tags: c#, linq, inner-join

Similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10824057/1663715), I have anonymous object which contains both Proudct and LanguageAttribute. Then I needed to update Proudct object's property like this:

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProductList()
{

    var result = from p in db.Products
                 join la in db.LanguageAttribute on p.ID equals la.ID
                 where l.LanguageID == "en-US"
                 select new { Proudct = p, Description = la.Description };
    result.ToList().ForEach(i => i.Proudct.Description = i.Description);

    return ???
```

Now how do I return list of only Proudct from the result object to calling method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductList()
{

    var query = from p in db.Products
                 join la in db.LanguageAttribute on p.ID equals la.ID
                 where l.LanguageID == "en-US"
                 select new { Product = p, Description = la.Description };
    var result = query.ToList();

    result.ForEach(i => i.Product.Description = i.Description);

    List<Product> products = result.Select(i => i.Product).ToList();

    return products;
}
```

List does not implement IQueryable, so I changed return type of the method as well. If you still need IQueryable though, you might use query again.